# WSO2 IS Claims configuration from secondary store

Tags: wso2, wso2-identity-server

I'm using WSO2 Identity Server 5.10.0 configured in order to use ActiveDirectory as UserStore

I don't have the oportunity to add custom properties to the ActiveDirectory so I'm facing several issues in claims configuration.

To solve the issue I was thinking to user ActiveDirectory as primary UserStore and configure WSO2 claims in order to be stored and retrieved from a secondary userstore (a JDBC user store).

I configured all what I needed but I can't make it working. When I start the WSO IS ti complains because it can't find mapped claims.

More exactly I have:

```
system error while authenticating/authorizing user : cannot find suitable mapped attribute for local claim http://wso2.org/claims/userid
```

Once I slve userid it gives to me other claims till I return all to the primary user store.

I'm wondering if my idea is feasible. If I can select from where to take claims.. why do I get this kind of error?

Answer (score 0):

Actually, configuring the Active Directory as the Primary userstore will not have any difference when it comes to attribute mappings. Because all the userstores in the system should to have correct mapped attributes for these meta claim set and other claims which are marked as "Supported by Default".

The solution would be updating the mapped attributes for local claims with correct exciting attributes from your active directory. If you are having multiple userstoes, you can have different mapped attributes for each userstore domain. Refer [this](https://is.docs.wso2.com/en/5.10.0/learn/editing-claim-mapping/) document for more info.

You may find a list of mandatory meta claims which we must have correct mappings to create users in [this document](https://is.docs.wso2.com/en/5.10.0/learn/configuring-user-stores-for-scim-2.0-based-inbound-provisioning/).

Comment: I already did it... but it's frustrating when you can't add properties to Active Directory. So if we could user Secondary User Store in order to be independent by AD would be be simply great... In this way we may configure claims by using or AD or our DB

Comment: If your goal is to have separate userbase from the AD users, having another userstore will work. If you want to add additional properties to AD users while you are not allowed to add more properties to your AD, you can simply create local claims starting with identity, they will be stored in WSO2 IS databases instead of the AD(userstore) `https://wso2.org/claims/identity/<your_claim>`

Comment: Maybe I'm missing something. What I want is the following: add the user basic information (that is username, password, first name e last name) on the primary user store (Active Directory) and all the other claims related to the user  on the secondary user store (postgreSQL DB). Is this scenario feasible? Otherwise it seems to me a no sense choose from which user store take/store claims in claims configuration

Comment: You have misunderstood the configuration I guess. The userstore selection in the claim configuration was not meant for that. It is there to choose in which attribute of the userstore we are going to store the value for this claim.

You are thinking something like discussed in this blog. But I'm not sure how far this approach is matching with the latest versions of WSO2 IS.
http://xacmlinfo.org/2015/03/03/configure-attribute-sources-with-wso2-identity-server/

Comment: The easiest way to address this without writing code is to use identity claims to store extra claims, `https://wso2.org/claims/identity/<your_claim>`. If your claim URI is having this pattern, they will not be stored into the respective userstore, but in identity DB.

Comment: Moreover, if you need help you can post your questions in wso2 iam slack channel. So wso2 developers can help you ASAP https://join.slack.com/t/wso2is/shared_invite/enQtNzk0MTI1OTg5NjM1LTllODZiMTYzMmY0YzljYjdhZGExZWVkZDUxOWVjZDJkZGIzNTE1NDllYWFhM2MyOGFjMDlkYzJjODJhOWQ4YjE